# Applying custom view in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, custom-view

I have found the code in the link below that actually does justify text in textviews. 
https://github.com/shayr1/android

The problem is I don't really know how to make use of the code.

Any help?

Comment: just copy the file and set the package name.

Answer (score 1):

Copy/paste this class in your application. After that you can use it your xml as a normal view :

```
<com.yourapp.package.JustifyText>textview properties here</com.yourapp.package.JustifyText>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Have you tried it ? It seems like its not working or Im doing something wrong.

Comment: The problem is when I try to add app:justify property to the view, it says its not found so compiling error.

Comment: I am pretty sure you will not need that property. have you tried using the custom view without it :


    <com.path.to.package.JustifyTextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Justify test view" />